# JPA/HIBERNATE: How can Query return Non- Entities Objects or List of Objects with inner non-Entities objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is there a way to include a custom object as an inner object of the other custom object?
For example, I have two Entites:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String a;

    @Column
    private String b;

    @OneToMany(...)
    private Set<Bar> bars;

    ...
}

@Entity
class Bar {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String x;

    @Column
    private String y;

    @Column
    private String z;

    ...
}
```

I'd like to write a query which select a FooQueryResult object like:

```
class FooQueryResult {
    private String a;
    private Set<BarQueryResult> bars;

    ...
}

class BarQueryResult {
    private String id;
    private String x;

    ...
}
```

I'm trying something like below

```
String query =
        "SELECT " +
                "s.a, " +
                "new package.BarQueryResult(f.bars.id, f.bars.x) " +
        "FROM Foo as f " +
        "WHERE f.id = ?1";

FooQueryResult site = factory.createEntityManager()
        .createQuery(query, FooQueryResult.class)
        .setParameter(1, fooId)
        .getSingleResult();
```

But this ends with error:

```
QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 14 [SELECT s.a, new package.BarQueryResult(f.bars.id, f.bars.x) FROM package.Foo as f WHERE f.id = ?1]
```

Is it possible to do this and how?

Comment: Have you tried to only select the `new package.BarQueryResult(..)` without the additional `s.a`?

Comment: it couse another exception: QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [foo0_.id.bars] with element property reference [id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible out of the box. You should use select new constructor expression, but there is a restriction - the nesting constructor calls isn't supported, you can't write `select new FooQueryResult(..., new BarQueryResult)`
or you can use your custom ResultSetTransformer. But I suggest to create Transformer class and do it manually.

Comment: btw, you can use http://mapstruct.org for transformers, it help to reduce amount of boilerplate code

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the comma after `new package.BarQueryResult(f.bars.id, f.bars.x)` ?

Comment: this is not it, I'm fixing a question and removing comma

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the JPA/Hibernate API structure exists for manipulating database objects (entities). If you want to manipulate non-entities, then you best create your own custom collections outside of JPA.

That said, your Foo is the parent object (the 'one' side) of your Bar object (the 'many' side), the child. You can get your FooQueryResult (i.e. Foo 'a' and Bars) by doing four things:

1) Add a parent field in your Bar object (foo_id). Basically, child joins with parent using parent's primary key (@Id).

2) Create a many-to-one relationship with parent Foo on the Bar object, i.e.

```
@ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="foo_id",
    referencedColumnName = "foo_id")
  private Foo foo;
```

3) Create FooQueryResult as an object that returns the results of the query, e.g.

```
public class FooQueryResult {
  private String a;
  private String b;
  private String x;
  private String y;
  private String z; ...
```

4) Create the query (here using JPA's named query method directly in the child object):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Bar")
  @NamedQuery(name="Bar.FooQueryResult",
    query="SELECT NEW FooQueryResult("
    + "e.foo.a, e.foo.b, e.x, e.y, e.z)"
    + " FROM Bar e"
    + " WHERE e.foo.id = :foo_id") ...
```

Finally, in your Session bean, you can create a method to return a result list that combines your Foo and Bar objects:

```
public List<FooQueryResult> myResults(int foo_id) {
    return em.createNamedQuery("Bar.FooQueryResult")
      .setParameter("foo_id", foo_id)
      .getResultList();
  }
```

Here is another way you can achieve what you want in 5 steps:

1) Create the class of your Foo and aggregated Bar objects. In it, include two constructors: a) one that is used to construct Foo objects; b) another that is used to construct all objects, including Bars:

```
public class FooQueryResult {
private a;
private b;
private List<BarResult> bars;

public FooQueryResult(a, b) ...
public FooQueryResult(a, b, List<Bar> bars) ...
...
```

2) Create another result object that returns Bars only:

```
public class BarResult {
    private x
    private y
    private z
    ...
```

3) In the Foo entity, create the query that returns Foo objects desired, using the constructor that builds Foos only:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Foo")
  @NamedQuery(name="Bar.FooQueryResult",
    query="SELECT NEW FooQueryResult("
    + "e.a, e.b)"
    + " FROM Foo e"
    ...
```

4) In the Bar entity, create a query that returns all Bars for a Foo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Bar")
  @NamedQuery(name="Bar.BarResult",
    query="SELECT NEW BarResult("
    + "e.x, e.y, e.z)"
    + " FROM Bar e"
    + " WHERE e.foo.id = :foo_id") ...
```

5) Finally, create a method that returns the aggregate:

```
public List<FooQueryResult> myResults() {
    List<FooQueryResult> aggregate;

        for (FooQueryResult foo : em.createNamedQuery("Foo.FooQueryResult")
          .getResultList()) {

          // create a new result
          FooQueryResult query = new FooQueryResult();
// add Foos
          query.setA(foo.getA());
          query.setB(foo.getB());

          // .. then add Bars
          query.setBars(em.createNamedQuery("Bar.BarResult")
          .setParameter("foo_id", foo.id)
          .getResultList());

            // add query to aggregate
            aggregate.add(query);
          }
    return aggregate;
}
```

Comment: I known that I can do this that way. However, I'd like to avoid writing custom convertets from one structure to other. That the reason why I'd like to write query which returns aggregated nested objects, not flat list. Do you suggest it is impossible with hibernate?

Comment: In general, JPA does not support nested collection relationships. See this article: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices. However, see my edited answer, based on a workaround that provides the results using two queries.