# Spring JPA -> Map a ResultSet to a non-existing entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I need to map the return of a native query to an object

- Here is my native query

```java
@Query(value = "select collector from relation;", nativeQuery = true)
     Stream<RelationStatistics> findRelationsStatistics();
```

- Here is my object

```java
 public class RelationStatistics {
     private String collector;
     public RelationStatistics(String collector) {
         this.collector = collector;
     }
     public String getCollector() {
         return collector;
     }
     public void setCollector(String collector) {
         this.collector = collector;
     }
 }
```

- Here is my test

```java
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Stream<RelationStatistics> test = relations.findRelationsStatistics();
        test.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
    }
```

This test return me :

```
    org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [RelationStatistics]
```

This is an example with only one string attribut but the original native query is a big request so creating an entity will be too difficult.

I have find `SqlResultSetMapping` but I don't really understand how to use it properly

If someone have an idea of what its possible to do 0_o

Comment: maybe this helps... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207916/jpa-hibernate-how-can-query-return-non-entities-objects-or-list-of-objects-wit

Comment: Why native Query, in a JPA-Query you get the Mapping for free. try 'select r from RelationStatistcs r' and native=false

Comment: Not really, i can't add table relations because there is too much relations and this exemple may not work :c

Comment: Because my original request is more complex (45 lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here : [JPA : How to convert a native query result set to POJO class collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection?rq=1)

Using projection with an interface as an object with getCollector() method and map with this